# Make content fit to the width of the div

Tags: html, css

How can I make a text fit to the width of div. Here is my code

```
<div class="column">
    <a href="#" class="user_thumbnail">
        <img src="<?=base_url()?>/images/1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">

    </a>
    <span class="name">texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</span>
</div>
```

When I have tried to display the text, the text overflows out of the div like a straight line.
How can i do css to fit the text to the width of `<div class="column">` (width = 33%).

Comment: You mean the text does not wrap around? Have you tried to add "word-wrap: break-word" to the div's CSS?

Comment: please note the code edited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**`word-wrap:break-word`**

- Wrap long words onto the next line.
- Adjust different words so that they do not break in the middle.

So try the below CSS

```
.column {
    width: 33%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xX8wQ/1/)

Comment: It working great. But It start with new line.but i want it right side of the image with break word. I have no idea how can be done this. can you tell me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`word-break: break-all;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-break) (assuming you meant fit the *width* of the div, not the height like your title says)

```
.column {
    width: 33%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbTes/1/

Comment: Word break is not working.still the name text is appearing like a straight lineI have changed the code a bit please check the edits.