# How to make the long text to fit inside a small div?

Tags: html, css

I have the div with a specified width but the text inside it are not breaking down and fitting into the div accordingly.

This might be a wrong question. How to make it fit inside the div?

I believe its not possible for fit completely inside at least can it be fitted inside the div according to the width not height.

Css

```
.limit{
    width:50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="limit">
    <p>fasfhfhsjdhkjhdkjhfjkhdsfjkhdfjhdfiuhadfhjdfhjadskf kjahsdjfahdfuahsdf dhsf</p>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FK477/)

Comment: .limit{ width:50px;word-wrap: break-word;}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make content fit to the width of the div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994392/make-content-fit-to-the-width-of-the-div)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

All you need is [`word-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

```css
.limit{
    width:50px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="limit">
    <p>fasfhfhsjdhkjhdkjhfjkhdsfjkhdfjhdfiuhadfhjdfhjadskf kjahsdjfahdfuahsdf dhsf</p>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FK477/1/)

On the other hand, if you are not looking to break the sentence, you can also use `overflow` property set to `auto` or `overflow-x: scroll;` - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FK477/2/)

Comment: word-wrap is called now overflow-wrap, since according to mdn: "The property was originally a nonstandard and unprefixed Microsoft extension called word-wrap, and was implemented by most browsers with the same name. It has since been renamed to overflow-wrap, with word-wrap being an alias."

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for a way to resize the div's font-size to fit the entire text without word break or scroll, you should use JavaScript to detect if the text is overflowing and adjust font-size accordly:

```
function fitText(outputSelector){
    // max font size in pixels
    const maxFontSize = 50;
    // get the DOM output element by its selector
    let outputDiv = document.getElementById(outputSelector);
    // get element's width
    let width = outputDiv.clientWidth;
    // get content's width
    let contentWidth = outputDiv.scrollWidth;
    // get fontSize
    let fontSize = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(outputDiv, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'),10);
    // if content's width is bigger then elements width - overflow
    if (contentWidth > width){
        fontSize = Math.ceil(fontSize * width/contentWidth,10);
        fontSize =  fontSize > maxFontSize  ? fontSize = maxFontSize  : fontSize - 1;
        outputDiv.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';   
    }else{
        // content is smaller then width... let's resize in 1 px until it fits 
        while (contentWidth === width && fontSize < maxFontSize){
            fontSize = Math.ceil(fontSize) + 1;
            fontSize = fontSize > maxFontSize  ? fontSize = maxFontSize  : fontSize;
            outputDiv.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';   
            // update widths
            width = outputDiv.clientWidth;
            contentWidth = outputDiv.scrollWidth;
            if (contentWidth > width){
                outputDiv.style.fontSize = fontSize-1+'px'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is part of a test that I have uploaded to Github https://github.com/ricardobrg/fitText/

Comment: 3 years later and still the best solution :) thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Modified the class limit. You can show the entire text in a single line.

CSS

```
.limit p {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use font sizing in units of 'vw'.

```
.limit {
font-size : 1.3vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it like this. It's very easy.
Look how **number 4** is **Scrolled**.

```css
#ol_list li {
    width: 380px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: silver;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0.5cm;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    border-radius: 12%;
}

 #ol_list li span {
    display: block;
    max-width: 370px;
    max-height: 20px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<ol id="ol_list">
<li><span>text1</span></li>
<li><span>text2</span></li>
<li><span>text3</span></li>
<li><span>scrolled ghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhghghghfghfjhfghghhfghhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhhfghfghfghfghfghfghfghfhhh</span></li>
<li><span>text5</span></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the value of `white-space` from `nowrap` to `normal` solved my issue with fitting text to a fixed div.