# Make text fit within a div responsively

Tags: html, css

I'd like to resize my text inside of a `div` to shrink as it's parent `div` shrinks, instead of overflowing outside of the div or hiding the overflow. Here's my particular example of the issue:

[image]

I'd like to make the "Major" "Minor" and "Diminished" words shrink as the div shrinks, to keep the grid-like alignment for the letters to the right.

I already know this is possible using JS (and also a SVG workaround), but I'd really like to do this in just CSS. I've read a bunch of old posts and articles about how it can't be done with CSS alone, but I'd like to see if that's still the case. It just *feels* like there's gotta be a way to do it in css nowadays- it's such a basic thing.

The code snippet I included is a simplified version of this issue.

[image]

I currently have `child2` set to `overflow: hidden`, which produces the above. Instead of the text getting cut off, I'd like it to shrink to fit (without breaking).

[This question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565201/how-to-make-the-long-text-to-fit-inside-a-small-div) offers JavaScript solutions, as well as repeated media queries (which wouldn't be smooth). There's also putting the text in a `SVG`, which will make it resize like an image would. Is there some `flex`/`grid` trick I'm not aware of that does the job?

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grandparent {
  background-color: #FFD670;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 30px
  }
.parent {
  background-color: #FF70A6;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.child1, .child3 {
  background-color: #e07046;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: #5286d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1">
        child1child1child1
      </div>
      <div class="child2">
        child2child2child2
      </div>
      <div class="child3">
        child3child3child3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewport units for your `font-size`.

> One unit is 1% of one of the axes of the viewport. These can be useful for responsive design, that is, designing websites that look good across different screen sizes, taking advantage of the space available to them.

This helpful article on [Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) from CSS-Tricks covers everything you need.

You can also use a `min` and `max` function to specify the maximum and minimum `font-size`.

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grandparent {
  background-color: #FFD670;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  padding: 30px
  }
.parent {
  background-color: #FF70A6;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  font-size: min(max(30px), 2.5vw);
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.child1, .child3 {
  background-color: #e07046;
}

.child2 {
  background-color: #5286d9;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="grandparent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1">
        child1child1child1
      </div>
      <div class="child2">
        child2child2child2
      </div>
      <div class="child3">
        child3child3child3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the parent div might have a max-width property, at which point the parent will stop growing. If we use vw like this, the text will keep growing relative to the viewport's size, not it's parent's size. Perhaps this will take some calc() or max()

Comment: @JoshSilveous Yes, with a `min(max)` declaration for `font-size`. See snippet.

Comment: I think this is what I needed! It'd be nice if there was a unit like vw that referenced the item's parent's width instead of the viewport, so there's less magic-number guessing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to play around with this css property it will shrink the letters when screen shrinks

font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 0.2vmin);

put this property in this class .child1, .child2, .child3